# What is the noun of the adjective "warm"?

Tags: adjective, noun, word-formation

I was practicing with [this site](http://www.schubert-verlag.de/aufgaben/uebungen_a1/a1_kap6_wetter.htm) and it ask for the noun of the adjective *warm* and I didn’t find it in any dictionary. Please help me.

Comment: [I can't believe your statement from the question. Voting to close](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/warm)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question ***can*** be answered extremely well by online reference materials; see my previous comment.

Comment: Do you know what the noun is in English? If not, does your native language has a noun for it? If yes, then you could look up the English translation and then find the German, in case you don't have a "your langauge - German" dictionary available.

Comment: In the [Wiktionary entry for “warm”][w-adj] you find the corresponding noun [“Wärme”][w-noun] under “Wortbildungen”.


[w-adj]: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/warm#Adjektiv
[w-noun]: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wärme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be looking for

> Wärme

For example:

- kalt -> Kälte
- cold -> (the) cold
- warm -> Wärme
- warm -> warmth

If it is could outside and someone just left the house, he might say

> "Komm, lass uns zurück in die Wärme (des Hauses) gehen.
>
> "Come, lets get back into the warmth (of the house).